# How we can use langchain extraction with use input as vectore store

Tags: openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

I am building a document extraction and large number of pages. So, I decided to build with langchain extraction chain but in i couldn't a example from retrieving method with vectorstore. is there any possibility to develop with vectorstore ?

methodology for large pdf extraction with langchain and openai api

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.